# Autocomplete jquery and Rails4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete

I am building an app and therefore I need jQuery autocomplete. To understand how this works (just started coding few months ago) I created a basic articles/blog app.

My goal is to implement a basic search field for the titles of my articles. I'm using [rails-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete).

However I could install everything so far according to the documentation. But now I'm totally lost on how to make this thing work actually (I tried to implement it via the documentation but it did not work).

My question is how my code should look like to make this work?

Currently my code looks like:

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles
end
```

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find params[:id]
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new article_params
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit :title, :text
    end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160607060132) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end
```

Comment: There's a link to the source code for a demo at the link you provided: https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete.  Copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use Jquery UI, because this kind of functionality is bettre with js. This video has around 1 year hope works for you.

[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMz8HmrQ350)

Sometimes use a gem is not the best solution.

Regards